# (Munkres) Clarification in picture/drawing about quotient topology induced on a set.

Tags: general-topology

In Munkres, p.138, Section 22 (The Quotient Topology), example 3 he has the following:

Let $p$ be the map of the real line $\mathbb{R}$ onto the three-point set $A = \{a, b, c\}$. Defined by:
$p(x) = \begin{cases}
     a & \text{if $x > 0$} \\ 
     b & \text{if $x < 0$} \\ 
     c & \text{if $x = 0$} 
     \end{cases}$

[image]

My questions: Why doesn't $c
$ have a circle around it? Why do both $a$ and $b$ have circles around them and then **another** circle around both? **Basically how do you draw this in the first place?**

Comment: The lines represent the open sets. The draw is telling you that $a$ and $b$ has disjoint open sets but the unique open set containing $c$ is the total space.

Comment: I see, but why do the circles of $a$ and $b$ also have a set around them and $c$ is not in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These circles tell you what the topology is on the set $\{a,b,c\}$, i.e. they tell you what subsets of $\{a,b,c\}$ are open.

The circle enclosing $a$ means that $\{a\}$ is an open set.

The circle enclosing $b$ means $\{b\}$ is an open set.

The circle enclosing both $a$ and $b$ means that $\{a,b\}$ is an open set.

And the circle enclosing all three of $a,b,c$ means that $\{a,b,c\}$ is an open set.

That's all of the open sets in this topology, with a single exception: the empty subset $\emptyset = \{\}$ is also open. Depending on one's taste in pictorial notation, perhaps one might be inclined to draw a circle enclosing nothing for this purpose.

Anyway, the lack of circle around $c$ tells you that $\{c\}$ is **not** an open set in this topology.

Comment: $\{ c \}$ is not an open set in this topology because it's a singleton? and somehow Hausdorffness is preserved?

Comment: @urxwrt It isn't. $a$ and $x$ have no disjoint neighborhoods.

Comment: The reason $\{c\}$ is not an open set in this topology is because the topology is defined that way. The point is: the circles **define** the topology, by letting you write an explicit list of all the open sets in this topology, as my answer does.